# How do I modify this T-SQL query so that its ouput can be joined with a table in my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am using `SQl Server 2014`. I have the following `T-SQL` query (with its corresponding output given below):

```
USE mydatabase


declare @t table (StayID int)
insert into @t select distinct StayID from DateOfBirth

while ((select count(1) from @t) > 0)
begin
    declare @Id int = (select top 1 StayID from @t)
    declare @age_tab table (StayID int, Age int, Year1 date)
    declare @cage1 smallint = 2, @cage2 smallint = 5
    declare @i_a int = (select AdultCount from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id)
    declare @i_c1 int = (select [0-3] from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id)
    declare @i_c2 int = (select [4-6] from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id)
    declare @age int = (select Age from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id)
    declare @Year1 date = (select cast(datepart(year,ArrivalDate) as varchar) from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id)

    while (@i_a>1)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, (@age + 2), @Year1
        set @age-=2
        set @i_a-=1
    end

    while (@i_c1>0)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, @cage1, @Year1
        set @i_c1-=1
    end

    while (@i_c2>0)
    begin
        insert into @age_tab select @Id, @cage2, @Year1
        set @i_c2-=1
    end

    insert into @age_tab select StayID, Age, cast(datepart(year,ArrivalDate) as varchar) from DateOfBirth where StayID = @Id

    delete @t where StayID = @Id
end

select * from @age_tab

order by StayID, Age desc
```

The output of the above query is as follows:

```
StayID     Age    Year1
 101       54     2016-01-01
 101       52     2016-01-01
 102       42     2016-01-01
 102       40     2016-01-01
 102       14     2016-01-01
 ...
```

I want to join the output of this query with values from another table in my database. Given the above query uses temporary tables to perform its operation, I am unable to wrap it into a `CTE`.

The additional information I want to bring to my output is stored in, say, table "t2".

Let's say the output from the query above is temporarily stored in a table called "t1"

So, I want to do something like this:

```
Select a.*
       , b.Cty 

from t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b on b.StayID = a.StayID
```

How can I do this?

Comment: join your table with  the table variable @age_tab

Comment: Thanks, works now!

Comment: Actually, I think there should probably be a much better way to create your output. SQL works best with a set based approach, not with loops. If you wish to improve that, you should post another question and include sample data (as DDL+DML) and desired output.